# Yet another Java generics “incompatible types” compilation error

Tags: java, generics

I checked dozens of threads at stackoverflow and could not find an answer. So, let me show you the minimized version of my class:

```
class db{
    private int idx;
    private Connection conn;
    db(int _idx){
        idx = _idx;
    }
    void Connect(){
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://...connection string");
        //System.out.println(conn.getClass().getName());
        //^^^ prints com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
       db d = new db(1);
       d.Connect();
    }       
}
```

The code above compiles well. If however I try to convert it to a template class, it does not. The way I do it is like so:

```
class db<T>{
    private int idx;
    private T conn;
    db(int _idx){
        idx = _idx;
    }
    T Connect(){
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://...connection string");
        //System.out.println(conn.getClass().getName());
        //^^^ prints com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
        return conn;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
       db<com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection> d = new db<com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection>(1);
       //d.Connect();
    }       
}
```

And this results in a  “incompatible types” compilation error. I think, what I did is just basic - I checked the `conn` type is `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection` and then I provided it as a template parameter. But for some reason, it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This is the whole error message:

```
$ javac db.java
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
db.java:34: error: incompatible types
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host, user, password);
                                              ^
  required: T
  found:    Connection
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class db
  1 error
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if somone does `new db<String>`? What would be the result of `Connect()`?

Comment: When asking for help about a compilation error, please most the entire error verbatim, and tell us at which line of your code the error occurs.

Comment: Arr the first two were faster than me. Ok, then just a little advise: try to stick to the [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) which states that classes should start with an uppercase letter (`Db` [or `DB`] instead of `db`) and methods should start with a lowercase letter (`connect` instead of `Connect`).

Comment: What is your reason for making the class `db` generic in the first place?

Comment: @Paul. I said, it is a minimized version and there are some reasons to make it generic.

Comment: @meriton. I did it. Please, have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use generics in the code you have shown us, because as explained in meriton's answer you need to cast to `T`. It might just as well be:

```
class db {
    private int idx;
    private Connection conn;
    db(int _idx){
        idx = _idx;
    }
    Connection Connect(){
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://...connection string");
        return conn;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
       db d = new db(1);
    }
}
```

It may well be that there are other methods in your class which justify the use of generics, but you would need to give more details for us to say for sure.

**EDIT**

However, if you require generics, here is how you could do it in such a way that does not involve casting to `T`.

Here is the abstract base class:

```
public abstract class Db<T extends Connection> {
    private int idx;
    private T t;
    public Db(int _idx) { 
        idx = _idx;
    }
    public void setT(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
    public abstract T connect();
}
```

and here is an example of a concrete implementation:

```
public final class Concrete1 extends Db<JDBC4Connection> {
    public Concrete1(int id) {
        // I'm not sure whether the id is supposed to be the id of the type
        // of Connection. If so you should just pass a specific number
        // e.g. super(1) and get rid of the id parameter.
        super(id);   
    }
    @Override
    public JDBC4Connection connect() {
        JDBC4Connection conn = whateverYouNeedToDoToGetSuchAThingIDontKnowIveNeverHeardOfIt();
        setT(conn);
        return conn; 
    }   
}
```

You could have other implementations for other specific types, but the idea is that most of the code is generic, and so can be written in the abstract base class.

Some people consider it an antipattern to expose classes that extend a generic class, but are not themselves generic. You may prefer to make the concrete classes private and provide static factory methods to return them:

```
public static Db<JDBC4Connection> getJDBC4Connection() {
    return new Concrete1(...);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Consider a real world case - when `idx` equals to `1`, then we should use `DriverManager.getConnection(...`, but when `idx` is set to `2`, then we should invoke another method `SomeOtherDriver.getConnection(..`. How would that work?

Comment: @Jacobian It works because in both cases the return type is `Connection`. The whole point about generics is that you don't care what specific type of `Connection` you have (because the code can be the same for any type). If your code depends on knowing the specific type then it is *not* generic.

Comment: I should also add, that it may be possible that in general case we set connection to some NoSQL database or even to some caching database. I just want to generalize `db` class, so that I could instantiate connections to any possible databases like `db d = new db(1); // <- mysql`, `db d = new db(2); // <- postgres`, `db d = new db(3); // <- redis`. How it can be generalized?

Comment: Pleeeease. You are talking about generics and other stuff and it seems, like you know how to implement it. But in your example `Connect()` method returns one and the same data type. Can you, please, drop a couple of lines of code, so that it could be generalized just on two databases - say, MySQL and Redis, or MySQL or MongoDb. I provide completely different databases, because it's a general case and because I'm not sure whether if we set connection to Redis, then we should still return `Connection` datatype

Comment: @Jacobian Maybe you could have an abstract base class that has all the code in it that makes sense for all the different types of database, and then you could have concrete subclasses for each specific type.

Comment: "that makes sense for all the different types of database". But can you, please, generalize your example just on two databases, say, `MySQL` and `Redis`? I would definitely accept it as complete answer. You may not even use real methods, just say instead of `DriverManager.getConnection(` - `SomeRedisDriver.connect("connection_str")`. How can it be generalized?

Comment: @Jacobian Ok. I'll see if I can put something together, but it will take about 10 minutes.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your help!

Comment: As fo using " static factory methods ", I do not like the idea of using a whole ton of different methods for different databases, that do the same thing - like `getJDBC4Connection()` for `mysql`, `getOtherDbConnection()` for other database. But probably I do not understand your idea right

Comment: Will such overloading as `public static Db<JDBC4Connection> conect() {...}`, `public static Db<OtherDriverConnection> conect() {...}` work?

Comment: You could make a single method that switches on an input value (e.g. an int or an enum).

Comment: By the way, may I ask you a question? In your example `T extends Connection` where `Connection` is taken from `java.sql.Connection`. So, your class may work for some different `sql` databases. But since I asked about a general case, when there may be other databases, like `Redis`, `MongoDB` and so on and so no, my question is whether your example will work for such databases?

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host, user, password);
```

does not compile because the return type of `getConnection()` (which is `Connection`) is not known to be a subtype of the declared type of `con` (which is `T`, and specified by the caller of the constructor).

Therefore, you must add a type cast. One way to do this is:

```
conn = (T) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host, user, password);
```

Here, the compiler will warn you that the cast is unchecked, meaning the correctness of the cast will not be verified at runtime, but succeed even if the connection is of the wrong type. I therefore recommend the more explicit solution:

```
conn = tClass.cast(DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host, user, password));
```

This reflective cast is checked at runtime, but needs a

```
Class<T> tClass;
```

passed as constructor parameter to your DB class.

As an unrelated note, you might wish to constrain the T parameter, because you know that only subtypes of Connection are valid, and abide by Java naming convenctions (lowerCamelCase for methods).

Here is the entire solution:

```
public class DB<T extends Connection> {
    private final Class<T> tClass;
    private T conn;

    public DB(Class<T> tClass) {
        this.tClass = tClass;
    }

    void connect(){
        conn = tClass.cast(DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://...connection string"));
}
```

which can be used like:

```
new DB<>(com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.class);
```

Comment: Looks awesome! Will check it in a minute. But could you, please, explain what should we do if sometime we decide to use this class to set connection with other databases? Something like `new DB(com.mssql.blablabla);`. Will it work? I'm asking this, because this is what I really want to achive - to switch between different databases using one and the same class.

Comment: Yes, you can use the same DB class to obtain a connection to a SQL Server instance. However, if your goal is to write your entire code in a way that does not care which database you use, calling code must not depend on the kind of connection the `DriverManager` returns, but simply use the methods in `Connection`. In that case, the entire generics are useless because they convey information (the type of the connection) calling code should not make use of, and you would be better off with your original code.

Comment: @Jacobian The above point is the one I was trying to make when I asked if the class needed to be generic. If you have to keep casting everything to `T` to get it to compile, generics are actually working against you.

Comment: "However, if your goal is to write your entire code in a way that does not care which database you use". This is exactly my goal and I still do not quite understand what is the best way to achive it.

Answer (score 2):

You defined `conn` to be of type T, not to `Connection` like before. So tecnically, T (and therefore conn) can be any object, which is not what your connection method returns.

If you want it to be generic, you need to define it as `<T extends Connecion>.` That way it will match the returned type

Comment: What do you mean by `need to define it as `. `

Comment: Keep going, almost there.

Comment: Do you mean class `class db <T extends Connecion>{` and all the rest can be left unchanged?

Comment: Yes (sorry for the typos, writing from mobile)

Comment: It looks promissing. Thanks!

Comment: However, what If I create an instance of other database connection some time in the future? I think, if I hard-code `class db <T extends Connecion>{`, then in fact, it will be useless.

Comment: If your using DriverManager.getConnection() whixh returns connection, there's no other way, you wont be able to ise any cpnnection that doesnt implement this interface anyway

Comment: It still won't compile if you change it to `db<T extends Connection>` because the line `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://...connection string");` returns a `Connection`, not a `T`.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the template/generic type T could be anything.  Someone is allowed to create an instance of this class like `new db<Integer>(5)`, in which case the returned type from Connect would be incompatible.  The compiler sees this impossibility so gives you a compile-time error.

What is your intent in making this class generic?  What other type would you expect could be returned by your Connect method?

Also, typically in Java, one should use capitalized class names and lowercase method names.  Code takes a bit longer to digest when it deviates from typical coding conventions.

Comment: "What other type would you expect could be returned". I expect it to return types other than `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection`. Connections to other databases, for example.

Comment: You can just use inheritance.  `Connection connect() { return new JDBC4Connection(); }` ... as long as JDBC4Connection implements Connection (which it does).

Comment: That sounds really promissing, but could you, please, drop several lines of code to see the whole picture?

Comment: `class DB { private Connection conn = null; public Connection connect() { return DriverManager.getConnection("..."); } }`.  You ultimately want a connection, not a JDBC4Connection.  It doesn't matter that particular implementation is jdbc4 or postgres.

Comment: But in real world, if say I want to support just these two databases - mysql and postgres - and want to use one and the same class (using `DB` class and using `connect()` method and not something like `connectMySQL()`, `connectPostgres()`). How it should look like then?

Comment: I'm asking this, because in your example of `DB` class, `connect()` method returns always one and the same datatype. How it can be generalized on two databases?

Comment: well, something like `class DB { private String url; public DB(String vendor) { if("mysql".equals(vendor) ) { url = "mysql connection url"; } else {url="pg conn url"; }} public Connection connect() { return DriverManager.getConnection(url); }`

Comment: It's always going to be the same data type.  It doesn't matter.  A `Connection` object can be either of a MySQL or Postgres Connection.  That's how inheritance works.